# Error while executing the query in SqlLite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, telegram-bot

I am trying to add username, user id and many other variables after the user press /start in Telegram bot. But I am getting an error in this code

```
def add_user(userid, username):
    userCount = c.execute(f"COUNT({userIdColumn} FROM {info_table} WHERE {userIdColumn}={userid}")
    if(userCount <= 0):
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO {info_table}({userIdColumn},{usernameColumn},{isBannedColumn},{isSubscribedColumn},{userNotesColumn}) VALUES ({userid},{username},0,1,' ')")
        c.commit()
        db.close()
```

I tried declaring cursor() and even database inside the function but the errors I get are

1. `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 20532 and this is thread id 19184.`
2. `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "COUNT": syntax error`

I am also aware that there is a post about the same problem which unfortunately did not solved my problem.

My question is what is the correct declaration here?

Comment: Is `SELECT` missing before COUNT in your query?

Comment: and the first error 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError' is due to the way you are using the cursor `c`. you can have one connection and then create multiple cursors for the CRUD operation.

Comment: @Robin Oh I see it now

Comment: @simpleApp Yes i declared the cursor inside the function but i still have the thread error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the first error was adding `check_same_thread=False` as a paramter = `sqlite3.connect("Your db",check_same_thread=False)` and also you need to declare the `cursor()` inside the function

The second error was caused by wrong format as it should be `SELECT COUNT`